# How send tmp file in response?

Tags: php, file, response, temp

I wonder how can I send temp file in Laravel or with php funciotn.
I know that tmp file exist to the end of script or to its close time.

I'm crating tmp file with this function `tmpfile();`

I tried to send tmp file with

```
$headers = [
   'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
];

return response()->download($tmpfile, 'tmp_name.pdf', $headers);
```

But I got error `The file \"Resource id #968\" does not exist`

What I miss misunderstand or what I'm doing wrong? Should I first get file content for example by `File::get($tmppath)` and then return in response file content?

Comment: Is this Laravel?  If so please update your question to include this information.

Comment: Provide more information how are you creating `$tmpfile` and what are you doing with it before you're trying to send in as response.